# Heat equation with logarithm of the unknow function

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I have some problem to find a method to solve the following $PDE$:
$$\partial_t ln[u(x,t)]=k^2\partial_{xx}u(x,t)$$
The equations resembles a common heat equation, but the logarithm of the function $u(x,t)$ seems to complicate the solution.
Does someone have hints or answer? Many thanks.

Comment: Does your PDE equivalent to $\partial_tu(x,t)=k^2u(x,t)\partial_{xx}u(x,t)$ ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you try to write a solution as a complex Fourier Series, this should break down to a series expansion of $ax+b$. Of course, you will need two boundary conditions to fully solve the equation.

Comment: This is nonlinear 2nd order PDE. I don't think writing the solution as a complex Fourier Series is easy.